# Power Query Expression.Error: The Date value must contain the Date component. Details: 43831

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am using power query in Excel. I have a date column with date starting in 1/31/2015 and ending 1/31/2022.  I have the below line of code that works just fine.

```
...
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Reading", type number}, {"EM_Date", type date}}),    
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [EM_Date] <= #date(2021, 12, 31)),
...
```

Now if I change the code just slightly like below It stops working and gives me an error. "Power Query Expression.Error: The Date value must contain the Date component. Details:     43831"

```
...
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Reading", type number}, {"EM_Date", type date}}),    
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [EM_Date] >= #date(2021, 1, 31)),
...
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: I created a list of dates only using `=DATE(2015,1,SEQUENCE(7*365+3,1,31))` then loaded to PQ. I made the same filters as shown in your post and didn't get an error. Are you sure the error is happening because of that? Can you post the entire query?

Comment: something is wrong with your data or the remainder of your code

Comment: **I found the error in a prior step... The value [EM_Date] is calculated and the source Column were dates but not set as date type.** Thank you 
FlexYourData and horseyride for looking at my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that are coming to this post for answers. What I found is that the Column must be set to Dates. In my case I was calculating dates and the source column was not set as dates.

***Hope this helps you!***